# coverage dont work in flexmojos-maven-plugin

Tags: apache-flex, maven, testing, code-coverage, flexmojos

I try see coverage report. Add **coverage:true** and get error.
Without the **coverage:true**, but I need to know what percentage of code coverage.
It seems the parser attempts to parse each files as java, and not as as3, please help!

```
 [exec] [INFO] Running tests /home/oleg/IdeaProjects/RTB/Resources/target/test-classes/TestRunner.swf
 [exec] [WARNING] [LAUNCHER] Using regular flashplayer tests
 [exec] net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.ParseException: Encountered " "{" "{ "" at line 8, column 54.
 [exec] Was expecting:
 [exec]     ";" ...
 [exec]     
 [exec]     at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.generateParseException(JavaParser.java:10296)
 [exec]     at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.jj_consume_token(JavaParser.java:10172)
 [exec]     at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.PackageDeclaration(JavaParser.java:558)
 [exec]     at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.CompilationUnit(JavaParser.java:312)
 [exec]     at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.parse(JavaParser.java:137)
 [exec]     at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.Javancss._measureSource(Javancss.java:256)
 [exec]     at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.Javancss._measureRoot(Javancss.java:339)
 [exec]     at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.Javancss.<init>(Javancss.java:419)
 [exec]     at net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.ComplexityCalculator.getAccumlatedCCNForSource(ComplexityCalculator.java:102)
 [exec]     at net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.ComplexityCalculator.getAccumlatedCCNForSingleFile(ComplexityCalculator.java:139)
 [exec]     at net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.ComplexityCalculator.getCCNForSourceFileNameInternal(ComplexityCalculator.java:224)
 [exec]     at net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.ComplexityCalculator.getCCNFoWARN   getAccumlatedCCNForSource, JavaNCSS got an error while parsing the java file /home/oleg/IdeaProjects/RTB/Resources/src/prrPackageInternal(ComplexityCalculator.java:194)
 [exec]     at net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.ComplexityCalculator.getCCNForProject(Coojects/pt/clients/fp/resources/models/icon/IconModel.as
 [exec] ParseException in STDIN
 [exec] Last useful checkpoint: ""
 [exec] Encountered " "{" "{ mplexityCalculator.java:164)
 [exec]     at net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.html.HTMLReport.generateTableRowForTotal(HTMLReport.java:70"" at line 8, column 54.
 [exec] Was expecting:
 [exec]     ";" ...
 [exec]     
 [exec] 
 [exec] WARN   getAccumlatedCCNForSource, JavaNCSS got an error while parsing 4)
 [exec]     at net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.html.HTMLReport.generateOverview(HTMLReport.java:336)
 [exec]     at net.sourceforge.cobertura.rthe java file /home/oleg/IdeaProjects/RTB/Resources/src/projects/pt/clients/fp/resources/models/resourceloader/ResourceLoaderModeporting.html.HTMLReport.generateOverviews(HTMLReport.java:271)
 [exec]     at net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.html.HTMLReport.<init>(Hel.as
 [exec] ParseException in STDIN
 [exec] Last useful checkpoint: ""
 [exec] Encountered " "{" "{ "" at line 8, column 64.
 [exec] Was expecting:
 [exec]     ";" ..TMLReport.java:96)
 [exec]     at org.sonatype.flexmojos.coverage.cobertura.CoberturaCoverageReport.generateReport(CoberturaCoverageReport..
```

My build configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0-RC1</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <iKnowWhatImDoingPleaseBreakMyBuildIwontBlameFlexmojosForStopWorking>true</iKnowWhatImDoingPleaseBreakMyBuildIwontBlameFlexmojosForStopWorking>
                <storepass/>
                <includeTestFiles>
                    <includeTestFile>*Test.as</includeTestFile>
                </includeTestFiles>
                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                <coverage>true</coverage>
                <coverageReportFormat>
                    <param>html</param>
                </coverageReportFormat>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you try with leaving out the "coverageReportFormat" option? It's working for me, but I don't use that option.

Answer (score 0):

same problem for me,
solved with 4.0-RC2